# jsTree load children of child elements in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I am trying to load child nodes with ajax on jsTree. I can load child nodes of a clicked nodes using the callback method. However I would like to load more than one level in the callback.

Example:

```
           [{"text" : "Child 2", "id" : "2", "children" : true}, 
            {"text" : "Child 3", "id" : "3", "children" : true}, 
            {"text" : "Parent 4", "id" : "4", "children" : true},
            {"text" : "Child 5", "id" : "5", "parent": "4", "children" : true}]
```

As seem there I want to load a nested node. This does not seem possible. I have created a fiddle to illustrate.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kwkh2uL/2711/)

Comment: You need to give it the data for your children http://jsfiddle.net/2kwkh2uL/2715/

Comment: @LiviuBoboia That works. So I presume there is no way to use the parent child structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Livius answer.

```
           [{"text" : "Child 2", "id" : "2", "children" :[{"text" : "Grand Child 2", "id" : "12"}]}, 
            {"text" : "Child 3", "id" : "3", "children" :[{"text" : "Grand Child 3", "id" : "13"}]}, 
            {"text" : "Parent 4", "id" : "4", "children" :[{"text" : "Grand Child 4", "id" : "14"}]},
            {"text" : "Child 5", "id" : "5", "children" :[{"text" : "Grand Child 5", "id" : "15"}]}]
```

It is working when we use the nested children structure not the parent child id structure (Alternative structure as named on [jsTree.com](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)).

[Working Fiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/2kwkh2uL/2715)